# CipherInput stream is not Available until CipherOutputStream fully written

Tags: java, encryption, inputstream, java-io, protobuf-java

Basically, I am trying to read data over REST from cipherInputStream but it looks like it is not available until the other service which is writing to cipherOutputStream completes.

Other service is expected to stream the protobuf data as below,

```java
 @GetMapping(value = "/stream/data")
  public ResponseEntity<StreamingResponseBody> streamData() {
    StreamingResponseBody responseBody =
        response -> {
          try (org.bouncycastle.jcajce.io.CipherOutputStream cipherOutputStream =
              new org.bouncycastle.jcajce.io.CipherOutputStream(response, initCipher())) {
            for (int i = 1; i <= count; i++) {
              VehicleInfo vehicleInfo =
                  VehicleInfo.newBuilder()
                      .setId(123)
                      .setHandle(123)
                      .build();
              vehicleInfo.writeDelimitedTo(cipherOutputStream);
              logger.info("Encrypted vehicle--> {} {}", i,vehicleInfo);
              
            }
          } 
        };

    return ResponseEntity.ok().body(responseBody);
  }
```

My service trying to consume the stream using apache Httpclient, but the read operation at while loop seems to be blocked until other service completely writes to CipherOutputStream.

```java
        final InputStream content = closeableHttpResponse.getEntity().getContent();
        CipherInputStream cipherInputStream = new CipherInputStream(content, cipher);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = cipherInputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
          logger.info("reading bytes of length--1024");
        }
```

I expect to read from CipherInputStream while the other service is still streaming data.

Comment: Not quite sure how that attempted streaming is supported by the other classes but one simple thing to try is to `flush()`

Comment: No [tag:java-stream] here.

Comment: Are you using the same `Cipher` instance in both places?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the cipher Instance we used "AES/GCM/NoPadding" is blocking the call. We now used AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding on both the service. Now we could see both the servers are processing simultaneously.